# Type 'xxx' is missing the following properties from type 'ElementClass': context, setState, forceUpdate, props, and 2 more. TS2605

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm receiving the following error when trying to run my react app:

> D:/React/my-components/src/App.tsx
>   TypeScript error in D:/React/my-components/src/App.tsx(23,4):
>   JSX element type 'Confirm' is not a constructor function for JSX elements.
>     Type 'Confirm' is missing the following properties from type 'ElementClass': context, setState, forceUpdate, props, and 2 more.  TS2605

```
21 |         </a>
22 |       </header>
23 |      <Confirm />
   |      ^
24 |     </div>
25 |   );
26 | }
```

Here is my Confirm component code

```js
import * as React from "react";

class Confirm extends React.Component{
  render(){
     return (
      <div className="confirm-wrapper confirm-visible">
   <div className="confirm-container">
   <div className="confirm-title-container">
   <span>This is where our title should go</span>
   </div>
   <div className="confirm-content-container">
   <p>This is where our content should go</p>
   </div>
   <div className="confirm-buttons-container">
   <button className="confirm-cancel">Cancel</button>
   <button className="confirm-ok">Okay</button>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
     );
 }
 
}
export default Confirm;
```

And App.tsx code

```js
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Confirm from './Confirm';

const App: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.tsx</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
   <Confirm />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is my package.json

```js
{
  "name": "my-components",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "24.0.18",
    "@types/node": "12.7.8",
    "@types/react": "16.9.4",
    "@types/react-dom": "16.9.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.1.2",
    "typescript": "3.6.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.10.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.10.1",
    "tslint": "^5.20.0",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.18.0",
    "tslint-react": "^4.1.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thank all , i have fixed this error by run following command

> yarn upgrade @types/react@latest

Comment: Had the same issue. And this fix also worked for me. But why? So what exactly does happen when running this command and why does the error pop up? Can anybody shed some light here?

Answer (score 0):

I had a component named `Component.tsx` (camelcase) and a helper called `component.ts` (lowercase) and this seemed to make these become mixed up. I was importing them in the same file also so I just renamed the Component one.